# Does Allulose consumption interfere with ketosis on a ketogenic diet?

Tags: nutrition, sugar

Allulose is a monosaccharide otherwise known as [Psicose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psicose).

I've been seeing a few claims [[1](https://www.shortcutketo.com/is-allulose-keto/)][[2](https://www.dynamicwife.com/allulose-keto-review/)][[3](https://allulose.org/)] online that describe Allulose in extremely glowing terms, as well as pointing out that it has just passed FDA approval for skipping the 'sugar' in nutritional facts.

One of the claims is that allulose is keto friendly. So, does Allulose consumption interfere with ketosis on a ketogenic diet?

Comment: If it behaves almost identically to sugar, would it really be any healthier?

Comment: I mean I'm feeling some suspicion because I can't find a single place on the internet criticizing it.  When everything on the internet is talking about how absolutely amazing it is I start to get very suspicious.

Comment: @PCLuddite I suppose that would be the 'almost' about it.

Comment: @DenisS My thoughts exactly... definitely seems "too good to be true", at least.

Comment: I think it is important to realize that most low calorie sweeteners work the same way - they have low interactivity with digestive processes and are therefore not absorbed. They also have few side effects, but have been vilified by the sugar lobby, which exploits the testing process to point out that eating hundreds of times the safe dose causes extreme reactions, ignoring that it also would with sugar. This is not too good to be true, but is not especially better than sucralose or stevia extract, other than that the sugar industry apparently hasn't begun their FUD campaign against it yet.

Comment: Completely healthy and almost identically are vague terms. Let's have a specific claim that someone is making.

Comment: @Oddthinking How does that look?

Comment: @cpcodes To me personally, sucralose tastes terrible, which as a casual consumer is the worst possible side-effect :P

Comment: @cpcodes Studies have shown that artificial sweeteners have a negative impact on the gut flora [Google scholar search](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?q=impact+of+artificial+sweeteners+on+gut+bacteria&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) and maintenance of blood sugar levels [Google scholar search](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=impact+of+artificial+sweeteners+on+blood+sugar&btnG=)

Comment: This is a valid question. The linked sources claim that allulose is  sugar that is calorie-free and thus appropriate for ketogenic diet and diabetics. Most of the claims have been proven by studies, so I suggest to reopen the question.

Comment: Let's take the first linked source. It does NOT claim it is calorie-free. It does NOT claim it helps boost fat loss; it says it may, and gives a reference. It is vague about blood glucose levels (it "may help") and is a "great tool". It gives references and explains they are limited. It says it tastes "very similar" and "almost identical" to sugar, which is wishy-washy. It reports there *might* be side-effects, but links to studies supporting its safety. It makes no claims about tongues and caramelisation. So, it doesn't support any of the (far too many) claims in the question.

Comment: Please pick one claim. Please show exactly where someone is making that claim - quoting their words exactly would help.

Comment: The first source: https://www.shortcutketo.com/is-allulose-keto/ claims it's 1) keto-friendly 2) has only 0.2 kcal/g (officially calorie-free), 3) is not recognized as a carb in the body, so it does not affect blood sugar and insulin levels 4) naturally presented in foods 5) 70% as sweet as sugar, etc. There are may other sites claiming the same, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psicose). This is actually a known sugar in Far East. It's FDA approved. Most of claims in the said websites can be easily proven by studies (and most of claims seem to be true).

Comment: Quote: "Yes, allulose is Keto-approved. It is not ‘recognized’ by the body as a carbohydrate and is not metabolized as energy, but it is instead absorbed by the small intestine and excreted in the urine. It provides only 0.2–0.4 calories per gram of allulose, or about 1/10 the calories of table sugar, and because of this, it has no effect on blood glucose and insulin levels." ([Shortcutketo.com](https://www.shortcutketo.com/is-allulose-keto/))

Comment: @Oddthinking I was hoping that my lists would explain exactly what constitutes 'taste' (the tongue is what tastes, so I simply defined the terms) and would explain what I consider 'health' per colloquial reading, since the close reason given was 'unclear what you're asking'. I believe it's fairly clearly now. I don't think I understand the rationale you've given for keeping this closed. Should I create two separate questions for Allulose, one for Health and one for Taste?

Comment: Wikipedia discusses it under the name "psicose" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psicose

Comment: @Onyz, your questions about effects/side effects are very related, so, if you ask me, they can be considered one question. For the rest, others can decide, but for me, it's also related.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101788/discussion-on-question-by-onyz-is-allulose-a-new-healthy-sugar-that-tastes-beh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the US Food and Drug Administration (FDA)](https://www.fda.gov/media/106159/download):

**Allulose,** also known as **psicose,** is a simple sugar (monosaccharide) with the chemical formula same as glucose (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>) but with different arrangement of atoms. Unlike glucose or other common sugars, it is only partially absorbed and almost completely excreted unchanged with the urine:

> ...about 98% of intravenously administered allulose is excreted in the
>   urine within 6 h...When orally ingested, urinary excretion of
>   unchanged D-allulose ranged from 11 to 25%... The data indicate that
>   D-allulose absorbed in the small intestine may pass into the
>   bloodstream and be excreted in the urine **without being significantly
>   metabolized**. Unabsorbed D-allulose is fermented to short chain fatty
>   acids (SCFA) by intestinal microflora in the colon...or is excreted in
>   the feces.

Some short-chain fatty acids produced from allulose in the colon can be absorbed and provide some calories:

> the energy value of D-allulose was predicted to be less than 0.2
>   kcal/g...

To compare, table sugar (sucrose) has ~4 Cal/gram.

Allulose is manufactured artificially from fructose or extracted naturally from [sugar beet](https://www.savanna-ingredients.com/en/food/allulose/). So, depending on the production, it can be considered artificial or natural sweetener.

---

**Allulose is keto-approved.**

[Ketosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketosis) is a physiological state in which your body, due to low-carb diet does not have enough glucose, so it starts to produce ketones and use them as an alternative fuel. A keto-approved carb is a carb that does not yield enough glucose to make your body switch back to usual metabolism. Some people believe that ketogenic diet helps in weight loss or in treating epilepsy in children.

Allulose is a carbohydrate but is not metabolized in your body, which means it is not converted to glucose or anything else, so its consumption does not make you come out from ketosis when you are on ketogenic diet ([Food Insight](https://foodinsight.org/what-is-allulose-a-different-kind-of-low-calorie-sweetener/)).

[FDA](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/fda-brief/fda-brief-fda-allows-low-calorie-sweetener-allulose-be-excluded-total-and-added-sugars-counts) allows allulose to be excluded from total and added sugar counts on nutrition facts labels, but not from total carbohydrates (so, it is considered a non-digestible carbohydrate).

Despite being a low-calorie sweetener, the taste of allulose is similar to table sugar (sucrose):

> d-Allulose is a rare sugar with almost zero calories, sweetness that
>   is 70% of sucrose, with some cooling sensation and no bitterness.
>   *([Pharmacology and Therapeutics, 2015](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016372581500162X?via%3Dihub))*
>
> The taste is clean-sweet *([KF Tiefenbacher, The Technology of Wafers
>   and Waffles, 2017](https://books.google.com/books?id=jysUDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA182&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true)).*

---

**Safety**

Allulose has been generally recognized as safe (GRAS) by [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/media/106159/download).

> Like non-digestible oligosaccharides and fiber ingredients, the only
>   known side effect of D-allulose is gastrointestinal discomfort when
>   ingested in large quantities.

According to one study in [Nutrients, 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6315886/), the safe dose is 0.4 g allulose/kg body weight (28 g/70 kg) as a *single dose* or 0.9 g allulose/kg body weight (63 g/70 kg) as a *total daily dose.* Exceeding that dose can cause diarrhea, abdominal pain, nausea and headache.

Allulose is not that special, though; another sweetener with similar characteristics and metabolism is [erythritol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythritol).